# How can a program learn to map pronouns correctly?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, nltk

How can a program learn to map pronouns *correctly* to something else in the text?

For example, in text "Lisa beats Jenny. She is cruel.", I would like "She" to map to "Lisa".

Is there a known name for such algorithm? If yes, what is it?

Comment: Start studying Natural Language Processing. You'll be at it a while. By the way, why should "she" be mapped to "Lisa?" Maybe Lisa is beating Jenny because Jenny is cruel. The ambiguity there is going to give you fits.

Comment: @JimMischel: that's right. Without more context, humans would choose the first interpretation, which is the most "likely". A slightly different sentence could yield the opposite "Lisa has to beat Jenny. She is cruel."

Comment: welcome to SO! please review the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, especially the "Search, and research" part.

Comment: Another thing you might consider is what happens if the sentence is "Lisa fears Jenny. She is cruel." Now, one has a good argument that "she" refers to Jenny: Lisa fears Jenny because Jenny is cruel. Your algorithm has to understand that if person A beats person B, then most likely person A is the cruel one. But person A fears person B, then most likely person B is the cruel one. This is a very hard problem that has not yet been solved. See, for example, https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bf10/0ab39584a746d2ab04515b3f59f362d6c6bb.pdf

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called coreference/anaphora/pronoun resolution[[1](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/coref.shtml),[2](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref)] but it's more of a research problem than an algorithm.

See the image below for what the [CoreNLP online demo](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/) does with the sentence "Lisa beats Jenny. She is cruel". **Keep in mind that it won't always have the result you want/expect, though.**

[image: Result of CoreNLP on coreference resolution]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the information you are looking for can be found in this link, about NLP (Natural Language Processing) and using it in a CNN (Convolutional Neural Networks)

http://www.wildml.com/2015/11/understanding-convolutional-neural-networks-for-nlp/

Its also worth noting that CNN's are made specifically for 'vision' or image parsing. And in most cases a DNN(Deep Neural Network) is needed for such a complex requirement.

DNN/NLP reading can be found here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.03091.pdf

**TL;DR**

There is no specific algorithm, but rather a subset of multiple algorithms that can be used to infer the information above. Look into Microsoft's white papers on language research.

Comment: If CNNs are made specifically for vision or image parsing, then why would you suggest one for NLP?

Comment: CNNs have been used to create such a thing and for historical learning purposes it is important to note why there was a move from CNNs to DNNs, which is outlined in both of those papers.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing such a sentence requires a great deal of common knowledge. You need to know that beating someone can be considered a cruel behavior. As far as I know no one has managed to really handle this in unconstrained speech.

IMO, machine learning techniques would fail because they work without understanding, by merely reproducing learnt patterns. but think that "Lisa beats Jenny. She is cruel." and "Lisa beats Jenny. She is blond." are structurally identical but you can't generalize one from the other.

Some systems such as Google translation work by reusing already seen fragments, i.e. short word sequences. But in your case, the patterns can straddle several sentences and their probabilities of re-occurrence it too small.

Comment: It also depends on what sense of the word "beats" you're talking about. Perhaps Lisa beats Jenny at chess. Or poker. Without knowledge of the larger context, those two statements "Lisa beats Jenny. She is cruel." are either ambiguous or nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *[neuralcoref](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref)* library from huggingface.

```
import neuralcoref
import spacy.cli
spacy.cli.download("en_core_web_sm")
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp,greedyness=0.55)
doc=nlp('Lisa beats Jenny. She is cruel.')
print('coref:',doc._.coref_clusters)
```

output:

```
coref: [Lisa: [Lisa, She]]
```

However, it wouldn't necessarily map correct nouns. The ambiguity will be difficult to interpret. You can do some tweaking in the parameters though.